# URL for a blogger blog issue

Tags: redirects, url, blogger

I am hosting the URL (`www.getyourpansoff.com`) of a friend as an add-on in a bluehost account. I want to use this URL for her blog (`get-your-pans-off.blogspot.com`).

I have configured the URL in the blog itself, and Google seems happy with it.

However, when I try to open the blog using `www.getyourpansoff.com`, I do not see the blog.

In BlueHost, I have the following:

[image]

I also have a redirection:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how to solve it?

**Update**

What I have now:

```
A     record www -> 69.195.124.93
CNAME record www.getyourpansoff -> getyourpansoff.com
```

and not redirection.

Still does not work.

Comment: Is this now solved as getyourpansoff.com is now directing to a website?

Comment: No, it should point to a blog at: get-your-pans-off.blogspot.com

Comment: Is it your site that getyourpansoff.com is currently displaying?

Comment: Yes. I have just made some modifications to have www point to Google. The instructions say to wait up to 24 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found those [instructions](http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/static.py?hl=en&ts=1233381&page=ts.cs). It works now.

Answer (score 0):

On 'A' (host), there should be `www` instead of `www.getyourpansoff`.

The redirect url may should point to `http://get-your-pans-off.blogspot.com`.

If you want to display `getyourpansoff.com` instead of `blogspot`, this is server side stuff, could be solved with mod-rewrite.

Comment: I have tried what you said, but it did not solve the issue. See my updated question.